# Pygame window not intractable

Tags: python, pygame

Recently, I started to take a look at pygame, but now I´m facing a serious problem. I followed the tutorial by "KidsCanCode" on Youtube and now have this code:

```
# Pygame template - skeleton for a new pygame project
import pygame
import random

WIDTH = 600
HEIGHT = 480
FPS = 30

# define colors
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
RED = (255, 0, 0)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
BLUE = (0, 0, 255)

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    # sprite for the Player
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.Surface((50, 50))
        self.image.fill(GREEN)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.centerx = WIDTH / 2
        self.rect.bottom = HEIGHT - 10
        self.speedx = 0

    def update(self):
        self.speedx = 0
        keystate = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keystate[pygame.K_LEFT]:
            self.speedx = -5
        if keystate[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            self.speedx = 5
        self.rect.x += self.speedx
        if self.rect.right > WIDTH:
            self.rect.right = WIDTH
        if self.rect.left < 0:
            self.rect.left = 0

# initialize pygame and create window
pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption("My Game")
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
player = Player()
all_sprites.add(player)

# Game loop
running = True
while running:
    # keep loop runnig at the right speed
    clock.tick(FPS)
    # Process input (events)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        # check for closing window
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
    # Update
    all_sprites.update()

    # Draw / render
    screen.fill(BLACK)
    all_sprites.draw(screen)
    # *after* drawing everything, flip the display
    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
```

The code itself is working fine, the pygame window appears and I can see the green sprite. But when I try to control the sprite via arrow keys, I only control the cursor in the text editor, I wrote the script in.
If I didn't open the text editor in full screen mode, the pygame window even disappears to behind the editor´s window. When I move the editor aside / minimize it, and click on the pygame window it still doesn't´t get focused.
I´m using a Mac, macOS 10.12.4, Python 3.6.0, Anaconda 4.3.1. 
When I try to go to the pygame window via "cmd + tab", it doesn't´t even appear in the list.
I installed pygame via pip.

I hope someone has either seen this problem before / has an idea to fix this.

Comment: This seems to be an issue related to the bug reported [here](https://github.com/ehmatthes/pcc/issues/19). If you are running pygame in a virtual environment, it seems to prevent the window from coming into focus.  The current solution offered is to run pygame outside of a virtual environment and wait until they fix the bug.

Answer (score 0):

I had that bug sometime ago as well. It seems like either the pygame module is buggy on Mac OS or Mac OS is preventing from being intractable. Try running the code on Windows or install a different version of pygame.